# ejecutar codigo en todas las 3 hojas en excel

Tags: excel, vba

Expertos buenos días

Como puedo hacer para agregarle a este código para que se ejecute al mismo tiempo en las 3 hojas cuando realice cada cambio de numero en la celda A1

```html
Sub Controldenúmero1_Cambiar()
Dim n As Integer
For n = 1 To Len([A1])
BuscarÁrea n, Mid([A1], n, 1), 4, 13
BuscarÁrea n, Mid([A1], n, 1), 17, 26
Next

End Sub
'y este es el complemento

Sub BuscarÁrea(n As Integer, Número As Integer, x1 As Long, x2 As Long)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

y = (n - 1) * 2 + 5 'empieza en col E
aTablas:
Range(Cells(x1, y), Cells(x2, y)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
For x = x1 To x2
If Cells(x, y) = Número Then
Cells(x, y).Interior.Color = vbYellow
'pasa a la tbla siguiente
GoTo siguenTablas
End If
Next

siguenTablas:
'sigue con otras tablas
y = y + 9
If y > 57 Then Exit Sub
GoTo aTablas
End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IaQEHMb9mQmH8ZnTyaMc6pvJtThzuWTP

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Cómo que se ejecute a la vez en 3 hojas? ¿Te refieres a que se ejecute el código una vez por cada hoja?

Comment: experto es que el codigo funciona de acuerdo al numero que esta en la celda a1 en cada una de las hojas y pues me toca colocar ese numero en cada una de las hojas para poder analizar las celdas que se colorean de amarillo y la idea es que el numero que se coloque en la celda a1 de la primera hoja (actual) se coloque en la calda a1 de las dos siguientes hojas

Comment: Si solamente es que la celda A1 de estas 3 hojas tenga el mismo valor, simplemente vincúlalas. Vete a las celdas A1 de las hojas que quieres vincular, y escribe `=TuhojaPrincipal!A1`. Así, con cambiar el valor de tu primera hoja, automáticamente se cambia en las otras 2.

Comment: pero en cual parte de los dos codigos va ese cambio maestro

Comment: experto ya hice el cambio en las hojas y si es parte de lo que quiero pero en la hoja 2 y 3 no se realiza la marcacion de color amarillo en las celdas de las tablas de mi imagen

Comment: Tendrás que modificar tu código para que se ejecute en cada 1 de las 3 hojas. Añadele un bucle usando `For...Next`

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que siempre quieras ejecutar el código en las mismas 3 hojas, este código te servirá. Es un bucle en el que va cambiando de hoja, y ejecutando tu código:

```
Sub BUCLE_HOJAS()

Dim MisHojas As Variant
Dim ZZ As Byte

MisHojas = Array("actual", "anterior1", "anterior2") 'poner aquí nombre de las hojas en las que se quiera ejecutar el código

For ZZ = 0 To UBound(MisHojas) Step 1
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MisHojas(ZZ)).Activate
    Controldenúmero1_Cambiar
Next ZZ

Erase MisHojas


End Sub
```

Mételo en el mismo módulo que tienes tu código.

Comment: lo añadi pero no sucede nada algun otro consejo

Comment: ¿cómo que no sucede nada?

Comment: He descargado tu archivo, y lo he ejecutado, y tu macro se ejecuta en las 3 hojas, que es o que querías De hecho, después de ejecutarla, la hoja "anterior2" es diferente. Los números que estaban en rojo, ahora están en amarillo. Así que la macro funciona.

Comment: entonces el codigo esta bien pero deberia agregarlo a cual de los dos codigos mios al primero o al complemento

Comment: El código que yo he diseñado es un procedimiento nuevo, que a su vez va seleccionando cada hoja de tu libro, y ejecutando tus procedimientos. Simplemente copia el código en un módulo y ejecútalo.

Comment: me puede enviar el trabajo a este correo jhonfredy66@outlook.es

Comment: No lo tengo guardado, lo hice en el momento y al ver que funcionaba, lo cerré. Pero simplemente tienes que copiar el código en el mismo módulo que tus otros códigos, y ejecutarlo, y listo.

Comment: no , me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Pues algo no estás haciendo bien porque el código funciona perfectamente. ¿Ejecutas el sub correctamente? ¿Te salta algún error? Ejecútalo si no depurando con F8